# Summary Statistics in a table format in R

Tags: r

How can I create a table of summary statistics for the number of observations

Answer (score 1):

Use `sapply` to go to each column and do the calculations.

```
sapply(mtcars, \(x) c(n = length(x), mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x),
                      median = median(x), min = min(x), max = max(x),
                      nMissing = sum(is.na(x)) ))
#               mpg       cyl     disp        hp       drat         wt      qsec
#n        32.000000 32.000000  32.0000  32.00000 32.0000000 32.0000000 32.000000
#mean     20.090625  6.187500 230.7219 146.68750  3.5965625  3.2172500 17.848750
#sd        6.026948  1.785922 123.9387  68.56287  0.5346787  0.9784574  1.786943
#median   19.200000  6.000000 196.3000 123.00000  3.6950000  3.3250000 17.710000
#min      10.400000  4.000000  71.1000  52.00000  2.7600000  1.5130000 14.500000
#max      33.900000  8.000000 472.0000 335.00000  4.9300000  5.4240000 22.900000
#nMissing  0.000000  0.000000   0.0000   0.00000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000
#                 vs         am       gear    carb
#n        32.0000000 32.0000000 32.0000000 32.0000
#mean      0.4375000  0.4062500  3.6875000  2.8125
#sd        0.5040161  0.4989909  0.7378041  1.6152
#median    0.0000000  0.0000000  4.0000000  2.0000
#min       0.0000000  0.0000000  3.0000000  1.0000
#max       1.0000000  1.0000000  5.0000000  8.0000
#nMissing  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several function to complete that:

`summary()` can help you get mean, median, min and max of your data

`length()` can make you get the number of observations

`sd()` to calculate sd

`sum(is.na(your data))` for number of missing observations for data